# How to remove space in between bars in HighCharts bar chart?

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart, react-highcharts

[image]

I'm trying to make a simple bar chart using HighCharts.

I'd like to remove the space in between the bars. My research led me to believe that the properties `groundPadding` and `pointPadding` were responsible for this space. But setting both to `0` did not change anything.

```
const config = {
      chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        spacingTop: 0,
        spacingRight: 0,
        spacingBottom: 0,
        spacingLeft: 0,
        // marginTop: 0,
        // marginRight: 0,
        // marginBottom: 0,
        // marginLeft: 0
      },
      title: {
        text: null
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      credits: {
        text: ''
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: options.map(option => option.option),
        // lineWidth: 0,
        // tickWidth: 0,
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        tickAmount: 0,
        showFirstLabel: false,
        showLastLabel: false
      },
      series: [{
        data: options.map(option => option.votes)
      }],
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
          }
        },
        series: {
          pointWidth: 20,
          groundPadding: 0,
          pointPadding: 0
        }
      }
    };
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Not sure if relevant, but the red `div` wrapping my chart is:

```
<div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', margin: 'auto', border: '2px solid red' }}>
    <ReactHighCharts config={config}></ReactHighCharts>
</div>
```

And the green `div` has dimensions: `width: 350px` and `height: 400px`

Demo: https://remove-space-between-bar-hbslv6.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 4):

`groundPadding` and `pointPadding` will be inside `bar` instead of `series`

```
plotOptions: {
  bar: {
    groupPadding: 0,
    pointPadding: 0,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
    }
  }
},
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/remove-space-between-bar?embed=1&file=index.js)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't do anything. Do you think it's  because of the dimensions of the div wrapping it? (I added an edit if that's the case)

Comment: Add live example or edit my example to show error you are facing

Comment: Made a demo here: https://remove-space-between-bar-hbslv6.stackblitz.io

Comment: I think error is due to `pointWidth: 20,` in series plot options. remove it and it will work .demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/remove-space-between-bar-aqp3ua?file=index.js

Comment: I see, but what I’m trying to achieve is to have a set bar width regardless of how many categories i have on the xAxis. And the chart height gets longer depending on how many bars I have. How would I do this ?

Comment: you can use [scroll for highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/224-scrollbars-for-any-axis/). Chart height will not increase

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in your code. You set `groundPadding` instead of `groupPadding`. Also, if you are using `pointPadding` and `groupPadding`, setting `pointWidth` before them will not take effect, as `pointWidth` is calculated based on these two parameters. If you want to have one width for all points, set only `pointWidth` property. As for increasing height of the chart each time another point is added, you can check the number of points on load event and change chart size adequately using `chart.setSize` function. Take a look at the example below.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart.html#setSize

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/221k5wLh/